# FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-positive-karma-92110-1]

Tags: android, mysql, pdo

I am trying to push notifications via PushBots. When i try to push notification from console my app "unfortunately closed".

This is my logcat:

```
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472): FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCMIntentService-positive-karma-92110-1]
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472): Process: com.banko.tahminler, PID: 19472
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationManagerCompat;
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at com.pushbots.push.PBNotificationIntent.createNotification(PBNotificationIntent.java:166)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at com.pushbots.push.PBNotificationIntent.buildNotification(PBNotificationIntent.java:68)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at com.pushbots.push.PBNotification.generateNotificationInner(PBNotification.java:79)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at com.pushbots.push.PBNotification.generateNotification(PBNotification.java:67)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at com.pushbots.push.PBGenerateNotification.generateNotification(PBGenerateNotification.java:74)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService.onMessage(GCMIntentService.java:138)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at com.pushbots.google.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:224)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.banko.tahminler-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    ... 11 more
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):        ... 12 more
04-20 13:19:12.741: E/AndroidRuntime(19472):    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

and this is a part of my MainActivity:

```
...
@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Pushbots.sharedInstance().init(this);
...
```

Comment: you need to use addslashes functionof php because your string contain ' character. please check the manual of this function yourself. thanks

Comment: Do you get any error message? If yes, please add it to your question.

Comment: sorry i post a wrong question, i edited it.

Comment: was this ever answered or resolved ?  Is the culprit android support library v4 ?

Comment: How did you got through this?